# $x,y\in\Bbb R,$ find the maxima of $\frac{x+2y+3}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+1}}$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, maxima-minima, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

I want to use Cauchy–Schwarz inequality, I sqared $\frac{x+2y+3}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+1}}$ and got $\frac{x^2+4y^2+9}{x^2+y^2+1}$, not sure if I am doing fine

Comment: Hint: One of the vectors should be $(x, y, 1)$.

Comment: $x^2+4y^2+9$ is NOT the square of $x+2y+3$.

Comment: @Crostul Wow I didn't notice that serious mistake, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not that $$(x+2y+3)^2\le (x^2+y^2+1)(1+4+9)$$

Answer (score 2):

By C-S
$$\frac{x+2y+3}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+1}}\leq\sqrt{\frac{14(x+2y+3)^2}{(1^2+2^2+3^2)(x^2+y^2+1)}}\leq$$
$$\leq\sqrt{\frac{14(x+2y+3)^2}{(x+2y+3)^2}}=\sqrt{14}.$$
The equality occurs for $(x,y,1)||(1,2,3)$ and $x+2y+3>0,$ id est, for $(x,y)=\left(\frac{1}{3},\frac{2}{3}\right),$

which says that we got a maximal value.